# Opposite Venous Blood pH Readings In Groups Of Patients?

Tags: blood, blood-tests, biochemistry

Assume Group A and B are 2,000 people each. If one doctor found that, say, sodium bicarbonate alkalized all venous blood of patients in Group A, but another doctor found that sodium bicarbonate acidified all venous blood of patients in Group B, why might this be?

Comment: This was [cross-posted to Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/60579/opposite-venous-blood-ph-readings-in-groups-of-patients).